# add store points to the customer account in magento

Tags: store-credit

customer will order product from site.

if they got damaged product, they will return the product.

if some customers reject the product , we want to add store points for the customer account.

so using the store points customers can buy other products.

how to do this in magento.

or is we have to use some extensions for this.

please guide me about this.

thanks in advance.

Comment: Google on "Magento store credit" and you will find modules from Aheadworks, Magestore and Magecredit that should help you

Comment: hi, thanks a lot, i did in google ...so i confused, i got many.... did you used any one? want to choose some best one.....

Comment: All of them are fine as far as the code quality goes. For specific features it's put to you to pick one

Comment: No problem. Added the comments as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google on "Magento store credit" and you will find modules from Aheadworks, Magestore and Magecredit that should help you

All of them are fine as far as the code quality goes. For specific features it's put to you to pick one